# C# reference variables use clarification

Tags: c#, variables, reference

Being not a programmer, I would like to understand the following code:

```
A a=new A();
B a=new B();

a=b;      
c=null;

b=c;
```

If the variables are holding only reference, will 'a' be null in the end?

Comment: No, value of variable `a` wont be changed. The assignment to a variable of reference type creates a copy of the reference but not of the referenced object.

Comment: You are redeclaring `a`, you never declare `b` and `c`, your types mismatch. Please post correct code, otherwise we cannot answer your question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to divorce two concepts in your mind; the *reference* and the *object*. The *reference* is essentially the address of the *object* on the managed heap. So:

```
A a = new A(); // new object A created, reference a assigned that address
B b = new B(); // new object B created, reference b assigned that address
a = b; // we'll assume that is legal; the value of "b", i.e. the address of B
       // from the previous step, is assigned to a
c = null; // c is now a null reference
b = c; // b is now a null reference
```

This doesn't impact "a" or "A". "a" still holds the address of the B that we created.

So no, "a" is not null in the end.

Answer (score 6):

Assuming that all the objects a,b,c, are from the same class, `a` will not be `null`. It will hold the value of the reference `b` before its assignment to `c`.

Lets assume you have the following class

```
class Test
{
    public int Value { get; set; }
}
```

Then try:

```
Test a = new Test();
a.Value = 10;
Test b = new Test();
b.Value = 20;
Console.WriteLine("Value of a before assignment: " + a.Value);
a = b;
Console.WriteLine("Value of a after assignment: " + a.Value);
Test c = null;
b = c;
Console.WriteLine("Value of a after doing (b = c) :" + a.Value);
```

Output would be:

```
Value of a before assignment: 10
Value of a after assignment: 20
Value of a after doing (b = c) :20
```